# Argument type not conforming to decodable

Tags: swift

Not sure what to do where; I believe my type is conforming to decodable!

```
let dm = DataManager(networkManagers: [mockHTTPManager])
let ep = Endpoint(scheme: .http, host: "api.nytimes.com",path: "/search/repositories")


dm.object(from: ep, with: DisplayContent.self) {result in
    print (result)
}
```

where DisplayContent is a struct

```
struct DisplayContent:Decodable {
    var title: String?
    var abstract: String?
    var thumbnailImageString: String?
    var date: String?
    var image: String?
}
```

and I'm trying to create a method to generically convert data to an object, but I think just the singature is relevant here

```
func object<T : Decodable>(from endpoint: Endpoint, with object: T, completion: @escaping (Result<T, Error>) -> Void) {
    let error = NSError(domain:"", code:-1009, userInfo:[ NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Internet Offline"]) as Error
    let url = endpoint.url!
    networkManagers.first!.get(url: url) { result in
        switch result {
        case .failure: print ("failure")
        case .success(let success) :
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let content = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: success)
                print ("content")
            } catch {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error is "Argument type 'DisplayContent.Type' does not conform to expected type 'Decodable'" yet DisplayContent conforms to decodatble!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is expecting an *object* of type T (`with object: T`) but you are trying to pass a *type* (`DisplayContent.self`).

You can either:

1. Pass an object of the correct type (e.g. `DisplayContent()`), or
2. Tell the function to expect a type to be passed (e.g. `with object: T.type`).

Comment: Your're right. But let test : Decodable = DisplayContent.self does not compile, so I still can't pass DisplayContent.self. The error is still that DisplayContent does not conform to Decodable....

Comment: Compiles and works fine for me with either method I've given you. You just have to change your existing code as I've said. Either line, but not both. What is this `let test: Decodable = ...` you're doing now?